# How can I use kernel density estimation for heat map visualization?

Tags: standard-deviation, density-function, visualization

I want to know more about visualization and density estimations.

Basically, I have a large sample of location data and every location object has a duration in milliseconds.

I want to solve the problem: "How long a person is staying at that point" using heatmap visualization.

I have read about Kernel Density Estimation where data points are being grouped in bin-grids or kernels.

Thus, I would like to ask 2 questions:

- Should I calculate Standard Deviation (SD) of duration for each point or as a whole (i.e. with relation to other points)?
- How do I "transform" or "combine" SD of each point to a KDE?

Overall, I'm planning to do additive blending using Gaussian kernels 
as stated in this [reference](https://blog.mapbox.com/introducing-heatmaps-in-mapbox-gl-js-71355ada9e6c#ad17).

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Kernel density estimation is where you have a random sample of locations and you are estimating a probability distribution (in 2 dimensions in your case).  I'm assuming that what you want is to estimate a surface with the height being a mean duration (rather than a probability density).  You can certainly use "kernels" to get a weighted average over a grid of points which you can then feed into a function that will give you a surface.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for the response. What I am planning to do is stated [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/introducing-heatmaps-in-mapbox-gl-js-71355ada9e6c#ad17). I'm going to add the "intensity" of each location if they are very near to each other. From there, the heat map would show which area is "densed" (i.e. long duration)

Comment: The reference you give treats all data points equally.  There is no example in that reference of including a different "intensity" for each object.